# Create an Query Formula

Tags: google-sheets

How can i create a query formula, if the user code in the "respostas" sheet is "1" (for example), returns which names (for this user) have less than 5 countries. In other words give me the result of the formulas F, G and H combined.

Result wanted: Nathan, Sam and Anna.

it's possible to do a query, that relates both sheets with the condition of the user?

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GdL5psaLKDix7282AZXGvZJUlm7rfhU2x5KlKTjp6ig/edit?usp=sharing

Thank you in advance

Comment: add more details

Comment: Looks like you have updated the Google Sheet after posting the question. Please add more details in the question

Comment: Hello, I don't know what details I can add. As I mentioned I need to write a query in an app and for that I need to combine the 3 formulas that are on the sheet I shared. In other words, taking into account the user answers that are on the sheet "respostas", the wanted result should be the names in sheet "Folha2" that have less than 5 countries for that user.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could do it with a query combining columns F, G and H like this:

```
=ArrayFormula(if(A2:A="",,C2:C-vlookup(A2:A,query(filter({A2:A,COUNTIF(Respostas!B2:B,B2:B)},A2:A<>""),"select Col1,sum(Col2) group by Col1 label sum(Col2) ''"),2,false)<5))
```

[image]

or if you want to see the people with less than five responses:

```
=ArrayFormula(query(query(filter({A2:A,COUNTIF(Respostas!B2:B,B2:B)},A2:A<>""),"select Col1,sum(Col2) group by Col1 label sum(Col2) ''"),"select Col1, Col2 where Col2<5"))
```

Comment: Hello and thank you, the formula i will write in the app.

Comment: Hello and thank you, i need to write the query formula in an app. I don't think i can't start with =arrayformula.

Comment: I'm not sure how to help you with that, the question may need more clarification.